# How to get API name from address in registry value in IDA plugin

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

For example I have eax 7c9100a4 -> ntdll.RtlCreateHeap
I can get reg value in my plugin but I can't get the api name
How can get the correct api name from the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NameEx(BADADDR, GetRegValue("EAX"))
```